# How to handle missing Host header in Rails 3.1

Tags: http, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rack

I'm seeing several exceptions a day on a very low traffic site.  The exceptions look like this:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter,
  set   default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb:25:in `url_for'

-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

 * URL       : http:///
```

This is abridged for clarity, but there are no other significant identifying details.  There is no user agent or referer for instance.  What appears to be going on is that these are HTTP/1.0 requests lacking the `Host` header.  Now it's strange to me that this exception even occurs, because the domain name in question is canonicalized by nginx using 301s, therefore it's impossible to even reach the Rails app without using the correct domain.

I don't understand why Rails would depend on that header anyway, since it seems Nginx should be passing through the more reliable canonical domain, however I am not familiar with Rack internals.  If anyone has any guidance for how to best solve this I would appreciate it.

- Is there a good reason Rails/Rack is depending on this header?
- Is there potentially a Rack bug here?
- Should I inject the header with a middleware?
- Should I hack something in Rails to suppress it?
- Should I configure Nginx to reject HTTP/1.0 requests?

Comment: we unleashed the security audit robots on us, and they produced a ton of these exceptions via HTTP/1.0 reqs. still looking to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It may be impossible to reach the application without the client using the correct domain, but that's not the issue here. The issue is the server knowing the correct domain. Without a `Host` header and without a fully-qualified URL, how can the server know what host the client requested?

Comment: Good question, I don't know because I don't have the full request log, nor do I have any idea what kind of user agent sent this.  I'm not intimately familiar with the HTTP protocol, but the Host header must not be the only place where the domain is sent, because HTTP/1.0 doesn't require it, and nginx is definitely seeing the correct domain (otherwise it would be redirecting before it had a chance to raise an exception).

Comment: The host is not necessarily the only place where the domain is sent, but if the domain isn't sent anywhere, the error reported will typically be the absence of the Host header, because that's where it's usually sent.